# Webview no me permite seleccionar imagen

Tags: java, php, android

Tengo una app híbrida que funciona por medio de un webview. Ya tengo solucionado el tema de los pop-ups para el login de facebook o twitter. Sin embargo, al apretar sobre el **< input type="file"/ >** nada se abre. No entiendo el porqué. Alguien podría indicarme si hay alguna manera de abrir un input file para elejir y subir una imagen desde el webview?

Nota: El sitio web es en php, el webview solo lo muestra y la app no hace nada más que eso.

Comment: desafortunadamente los webview tienen muchas limitantes de funciones, revisa esta respuesta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview, igual y tienes que hacer mas que simplemente mostrar el webview

Comment: Gracias! por links contiguos logré encontrar la solución. Un saludo!

Comment: Continuo pensando que lo mejor seria que te mirases phonegap, muchisimas cosas de esas, viene implementadas te dejo un link de un foro http://www.phonegapspain.com/

Comment: Es que yo uso Android Studio, no phonegap con eclipse. No creo que pueda implementarlo. No conozco nada de nada del tema...

Answer (score 1):

El problema en este tipo de , específicamente [input.file](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html) es que debido a seguridad no permite su funcionamiento, simplemente no lo va a reconocer.

Si deseas realizar algo similar sería implementando [**WebChromeClient()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html), este es un ejemplo:

http://m0s-programming.blogspot.mx/2011/02/file-upload-in-through-webview-on.html

```
public class MyAwesomeActivity extends Activity {

 private WebView wv;

 private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
 private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
  if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
  {
   if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;

  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  wv = new WebView(this);
  wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
  wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
  {
         //The undocumented magic method override
         //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
         public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

          mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
          i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
          i.setType("image/*");
          MyAwesomeActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

         }
  });

  setContentView(wv);
 }
```

Comment: Ya lo tenía implementado, pero su funcionamiento se basaba en crear varias pestañas dentro del webview para "handle" las pop ups de facebook y twitter. Ya solucioné el problema, pero no se como hacerlo funcionar con android superior al 4.4

Comment: @Criss te ruego que me ayudes con esto, no encuentro solución